# Convert a number to a specific format without return

Tags: php, function

PHP's [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function returns a formatted number.

I want to make a function to convert a number to that format without a return.

So, I am trying to use a void function but the number is not converted.

```
<?php

function format_number_($number)
{
 $number =  number_format($number,2,'.',',');    
}

$a = 10500100;

format_number_($a); 
echo  $a;
?>
```

I want to output `$a` as a formatted number. The number `10500100` should be converted to `10,500,100.00`. Instead it echoes `10500100`, same as originally assigned.

Comment: try `function format_number_(&$number)` to pass it by reference.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *I want to convert the number to that format, not replace it*?

Comment: You need to return from the function. You're echoing `$a = 10500100;` which I don't know why.

Comment: You are missing a return statement. [Rubber Ducking](https://www.google.com/search?q=Rubber+ducking)

Comment: Here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8208c2824409137325516d6a76de920334002c8b - which is what I said in [my above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240575/convert-a-number-to-a-specific-format#comment102853565_58240575). Typographical error made here.

Comment: actually i don't want to return it. Just convert it. Imagine that i perform a select with 10 records and format all those numbers. I need to convert each number using function call and one parameter is this possible? I know i can do it like so: `$row->number = format_number($row->number);`

Comment: I just want to shorten it to: `format_number($row->number);`

Comment: @GragasIncoming please see my recommendation above. Try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db070735451dd76ff9ef319c9722e60e9cc5db0c)

Comment: Yes that's what i wanted to do, thanks @Ruzihm

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner You don't need to return anything from this function if you pass by reference. See my answer.

Comment: My title is different than others. Google search will bring my question to more people. "Convert" is the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the variable by reference using `&` such as `function format_number_(&$number)`:

```
<?php
function format_number_(&$number)
{
 $number =  number_format($number,2,'.',','); 
}

$a = 10500100;

format_number_($a); 

echo $a;
?>
```

This way, assignments to `$number` in the function also apply to the variable that was passed in.